# Detectar si existe el directorio Documents en Android

Tags: java, android

Veo que algunos dispositivos tienen la carpeta "Documents" y otros no, dependiendo de la versión de Android

¿Cómo se puede detectar si la carpeta `Documents` existe y si no existe crearla?

Es por una app que necesito almacenar ficheros en el sistema de ficheros y que pueda usar en otras apps.

Tengo lo siguiente para detectar la ruta absoluta:

```
File outDir;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    outDir =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).toString());
} else {
    outDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Documents").toString());
}
```

con eso se obtiene:

> /storage/sdcard0/Documents

Comment: Mi duda es cual vendría siendo la carpeta de Documents de android, yo en mi teléfono no la encuentro, pero de igual manera te podría servir el código File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Main");
if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
    // do something here
} siempre y cuando conozcas el path del directorio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el comentario de @Bourne he creado lo siguiente

Con `mkdir` se crean los directorios.

```
Log.d(TAG, "isDirectory(): " + outDir.isDirectory());
boolean mBool;
if ((!outDir.exists()) && (outDir.isDirectory())) {
    mBool = outDir.mkdir();
    Log.d(TAG, "Create Dir: " + outDir + "result: " + mBool);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Exist: " + outDir);

}
```

Otra manera si se requiere más de una vez recurrir a crear directorios

```
public class FileDirUtils {


    private static final String TAG = FileDirUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    public static boolean existDirectory(File dir) {
        return !((!dir.exists()) && (dir.isDirectory()));
    }

    public static boolean createDirectory(File dir) {
        boolean mBool;
        return !existDirectory(dir) && dir.mkdir();
    }
}
```

Su uso:

```
if (!FileDirUtils.existDirectory(outDir)) {
    FileDirUtils.createDirectory(outDir);
}
```